# Is this layout built with a listview/recyclerview?

Tags: android

[image]

I am unsure what they used to build this layout. I don't think it's 8 imageviews, however I am unsure if it is a recycler.

Comment: `what they used` please don't ask **US** how **THEY** did it. Ask **THEM** instead. As for what you can use - you can use just a layout with ImageViews placed in it, or a ListView, or a RecyclerView, or even draw images on canvas manually. It's up to you.

Comment: you should use a horizontal RecyclerView, and depending on the size of your items you can display 8 or less without the need of horizontal scrolling  or you can ever disable the scroll in recyclerView recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

Comment: That was what I was thinking hence the question. Should I just use 8 ImageViews? Or is there some alternative

Comment: you can populate them using Linearlayout on runtime(dynamically) or RecyclerView

Answer (score 2):

**You can use Horizontal RecyclerView**

```
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, 
LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true));
```

**OR**

You can use HorizontalScrollView  if 8 or less than data